# What are the efficient ways to connect SSIS to salesforce?

Tags: ssis

I am looking for the various means of connecting my SSIS package to salesforce connector.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Data Connection, and select the CData Provider for Salesforce.

Enter the connection details for your Salesforce account. In this example, we are using a Salesforce Developer Account for this example.

Required connection properties are User, Password, and Access Token. OAuth is also supported.

[image]

Open the ADO.NET Source editor and set the following information:

ADO.NET connection manager: In the Connection Managers menu, select the Data Connection you just created.

Data access mode: Select 'SQL command'.

SQL command text: In the ADO.NET Source editor, open the Component Properties tab and enter a SELECT command, such as the one below

[image]